# Change numbering format of captions word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, numbering, caption

I'm writing a `Persian` text (which is right to left) in `MS-word 2019`. I want to insert caption as below for my images:

شکل-1-1
شکل-1-2
شکل-1-3
...

where `right` numbers are `heading 1` and `left` numbers are `auto generated`. I can't make this format using insert caption. in order words, MS-word makes some-thing like this:

شکل-1-1
شکل-2-1
شکل-3-1
...

that headings are located in left side (I want to be in right side). is there any way to change this format?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I was able to solve the immediate problem by inserting a Right-to-Left Override character immediately after the figure / Shape / شکل ) caption. You can insert one by going to the Insert tab in the Ribbon->Symbols dropdown->Symbol->More Symbols.... Then in the Dialog box, click the Special Characters tab and scroll doen the list. Here, the character is next to the bottom, above the "Pop Directional Formatting" character. You should see the numbering switch from (say) 1-2 to 2-1 immediately for that paragraph.

You will also need to put a "Pop Directional Formatting" character after the numbering. That is, immediately to the left of the numbering. Otherwise, for example, a number such as 123 will appears as 321.

Word inserts figure captions by inserting the caption text (شکل in this case) following by one or more field codes, specifically a { STYLEREF } field code if you have specified that you want a chapter heading, followed by the separator ("-" in this case), then a { SEQ } field, which in this case will contain an ARABIC switch. When you insert the Right-to-Left Override character, you will see the word STYLEREF change to FERELYTS and ARABIC change to CIBARA, but when you re-execute the fields (select and press F9) they still work.

Although this seems to cause a problem withthe text format here, it does seem to generate the correct results when you insert a Table of Figures, but I am dealing with a copy of Word that's basically set up for LTR text so I think you will need to verify that for yourself.

You can also put the Right-to-Left Override character into the caption label by. eg.

- Put one after (to the left of) شکل
- Copy that text
- Go to References->Insert Caption
- Click *New Label...*
- Paste the text into the Label textbox and click OK
- Create the caption.

However, you will still need to insert a Pop Directional Formatting character manually, so you might be better off saving the entire sequence of

شکل,Right-To-Left Override, { STYLEREF } field,{ SEQ } field,Pop Directional Formatting

as an Autotext

and insert one of those when you need a new caption, then update the fields.